# Service Reference in UWP reusing NetStandard assemblies

Tags: wcf, uwp, .net-standard

In an client/server application I am trying to reuse assemblies targeting NetStandard1.4 in the Server and in an UWP. Communication is done using WCF.

If "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" is unchecked the service references is created. Once I check the option to reuse assemblies I get the following error:

> "Custom tool warning: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event."

and warnings saying:

> "Custom tool warning: Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event."

I found this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5092755b-e1ed-4496-ae6d-74386ebdac98/uwpservice-references-in-universal-apps-and-portable-class-libraries?forum=wpdevelop it is related to PCL and I hope netstandard has overcome that issue.
I have tried importing frameworks in my UWP app:

```
"frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {
      "imports": [ "netstandard1.4", "netstandard1.6.1" ]
    }
  },
```

but it didn't work. It seems like I am really close to have it working but I am missing a detail that makes everything work.

Comment: Any dependent dll in not present in the location thats why its giving you this error. If you uncheck Reuse types in referenced assemblies, can it run?

Comment: Hi @Scavenger, if I do not reuse the dlls the update services process works properly; that let me in a situation where I have to convert each entity between front-end and back-end. For now I've gone back to PCLs. It was like the process was searching for previous version of the assemblies and was not able to redirect to the newest ones. The app had System.Runtime 4.3 but it kept searhing for 4.0.20.